# Load all fields name into combobox in visual basic 6.0

Tags: visual-studio, combobox, vb6

How to load all fields name into combo box. I am using visual basic 6.0.

My code is like this.

```
Private Sub combo2_option()
    Call Dbase

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "select ID,DATE,REFNO,SUPPLIER,MODEL,SERIAL,DESCRIPTION,UOM,CATEGORY,PUH,GDP from product_aging_monitoring ", db, 3, 3

   Combo2.AddItem rs(2)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1. You can limit the records to 1 if you wish to get only the field names.

```
For i=0 to rs.fields.count-1
    Combo2.AddItem rs.fields(i).Name
Next
```

Option 2 is to use ADOX (DAO) Reference instead of writing a select query. Use ADOX.Catelog object to get metadata of the tables and database